# Rearrange array values according to another array values in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have got 2 arrays(One single and one multidimensional).

Single array "A" looks like

```
[questionid] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
            [1] => 13
            [2] => 55
            [3] => 15
            [4] => 16
        )
```

Multidimensional array "B" looks like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [quid] => 12
            [answer] => AAA
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [quid] => 13
            [answer] => neighbour
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [quid] => 15
            [answer] =>
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [quid] => 16
            [answer] =>
        )

     [4] => Array
        (
            [quid] => 55
            [answer] =>
        )
)
```

Now I want the array B (quid) values to be rearranged depending upon the values from array A. So in array B the value of quid last element(55) is at the very end whereas in array A it is in 3rd position.

I want the array B look like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [quid] => 12
            [answer] => AAA
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [quid] => 13
            [answer] => neighbour
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [quid] => 55
            [answer] =>
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [quid] => 15
            [answer] =>
        )

     [4] => Array
        (
            [quid] => 16
            [answer] =>
        )
)
```

The code for multidimensional array is

```
$ansid = array
(
     array
        (
            "quid" => 12,
            "answer" => "AAA"
        ),

     array
        (
            "quid" => 13,
            "answer" => "neighbour"
        ),

     array
        (
            "quid" => 15,
            "answer" =>""
        ),
     array
        (
            "quid" => 16,
            "answer" =>""
        ),

     array
        (
            "quid" => 55,
            "answer" =>""
        )
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Not** using `array_walk()` as to be mor demonstrative, you could just

```
$newB=array()
foreach ($arrayB as $b) $newB[$b['quid']]=$b;
$newA=array()
foreach ($arrayA as $k=>$v) $newA[$k]=$newB[$v]
//$newA has the required structure
```

Comment: Thanks but don't know why I am getting 'Warning: Illegal offset type' for multidimensional array.I am posting the structure in my question.

Comment: So stupid I am. Please ignore my last comment. Your solution is just awesome.Now I need to understand.Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

With the user sort function:

```
$single_array = ...; // order by the index of this array
$mult_dim_array = ...; // to be ordered by the 'quid' value of the elements

function my_comp($a, $b) {
    return array_search($a['quid'], $single_array ) - array_search($b['quid'], $single_array );
}

usort($mult_dim_array, "my_comp");
```

This will get the index on your first array to determine which element goes first or later. The function reads `$single_array` as a global variable (defined outside the function).

Documentation at http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php